# how display and hide the button with the value from database

Tags: php, html

how to create a button to hide the value of the database.
for example :

```
<a href="#alatrusak" class="btn pull-right btn-danger btn3d" id="alatrusakshow" value="<?php echo $detail['status'] ?> ">
```

value status = 1 and 2

if button1 value status = 1 results show

and

if button1 value status = 2 results hidden

Comment: What exactly do you want? for both value you want to show result!!!

Comment: `if ($a == $b) {
  echo "do something";
}`

Comment: @Parixit, sory i wrong write answer... i want one if the value that appears appropriate database then the button will be hidden

Comment: @irwanDwiyanto It's simple, just use `if....else` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Underneath your button you would just check the value of `$detail['status']`

```
<?php

    if ($detail['status'] == 1) {
        // echo results
    } else {
        // echo no result message
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks @redreddington, but i want button hidden if each of the database

Comment: OK sounds like you have posted incomplete code in your question then. Are you looping through a set of rows pulled from the database and want to show/hide a button depending on the value pulled for each row?

Comment: Sure, can you update you question to include all of you code including where you are fetching the rows from the database and how you are iterating through each one. If you are unsure about how to iterate through each one, that's how you should rephrase your question :)

Answer (score 0):

get the value from db $status=$detail['status'] ; and check if present and show it . very simple :)

```
 <?php
$status=$detail['status'] ;
if($status==1){
?>
<a href="#alatrusak" class="btn pull-right btn-danger btn3d" id="alatrusakshow" value="<?php echo $status;?> ">
<?php
}
elseif($status==2){
?>
<a href="#alatrusak" class="btn pull-right btn-danger btn3d" id="alatrusakshow" value="<?php echo $status;?> ">
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's it!! For more detail on conditional statement check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

```
<?php if($detail['status']=='1') { ?>
    <!-- Show anything you want to display when status = 1 -->
    <a href="#alatrusak" class="btn pull-right btn-danger btn3d" id="alatrusakshow" value="<?php echo $detail['status'] ?>">
<?php } ?>
```